# Simple select with trick

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to write a select which will list all of the Clients however here is trick if client has status 1 or 2 it should mark this client with `*` before name. It should looks like

```
  Vasya Pupkin 
* Masha Pupkina
```

select looks like

```
select FirstName + ' '+ LastName, Address, DOB
from Clients 
Order By FirstName
```

that means Masha is active client.
Spend almost 2 hours for searching in internet but cannot find anything useful. Because of that asking question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rely on the use of the [`CASE` structure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to check the status field.

Check this fully functional code with sample data on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7bbfb/1)

```
SELECT (CASE
             WHEN status IN (1, 2) THEN '* '
             ELSE ''
        END) + FirstName + ' '+ LastName as Client_List
  FROM Clients
 ORDER BY FirstName
```

Data:

```
[id]  [status]  [FirstName]  [LastName]
 1        3        Vasya       Pupkin
 2        2        Masha       Pupkina
 3        3        Sasha       Alexeivich
 4        1        Katya       Alexeivna
```

Result:

```
CLIENT_LIST
* Katya Alexeivna
* Masha Pupkina
Sasha Alexeivich
Vasya Pupkin
```

**EDIT**
Ouch! too late, muhmud answer is correct

Comment: Thanx @Yaroslav! I love ask questions when it is day in Europe and Russia :)

Comment: You are welcome. Alaska, that's far man. I've family in Tula and Moscow.

Answer (score 3):

```
select (case when status in (1, 2) then '* ' else '' end) + FirstName + ' '+ LastName, Address, DOB
from Clients 
Order By FirstName
```

Comment: Awesome! I was trying to wright case but it was throwing me bunch of errors :) !! Thanx

Comment: If the answer was correct, check the mark under the votes counter so others can see this is the correct and accepted answer.